# Import multiple database schemas in mysql in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

want to upload multiple database schema using backup.sql. Then when try to migrate showing **(1044, "Access denied for user 'pranay'@'%' to database 'core'")**
I have added snapshot of my files for reference

```
***docker-compose.yml***
version: '3'
services:
db:
image: mysql:5.7
container_name: mirror_core
volumes:
  - ./mirror/core.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/core.sql:rw
  - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
expose:
  - "3306"
restart: always
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mobigo@123
  - MYSQL_USER=pranay
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mobigo@123
web:
build: .
container_name: mirrorweb
command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn mirror.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
links:
  - db
volumes:
  - ./mirror:/mirror
expose:
  - "8000"
depends_on:
  - db
```

***core.sql***

```
CREATE DATABASE  `core` ;
CREATE DATABASE  `murad` ;
CREATE DATABASE  `mysqltest` ;
```

***settings.py***

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'core',
        'USER':'pranay',
        'PASSWORD':'mobigo@123',
        'HOST':'db',
        'PORT':'',
    }
}
```

steps are as follows : docker-compose build >> docker-compose up >> docker-compose exec web bash >> python manage.py migrate (within docker container)
**on migrate getting error as (1044, "Access denied for user 'pranay'@'%' to database 'core'")**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `@` in the password. You need to escape it in you docker-compose.yml Python uses password with @123 while compose treats it differently and therefore is not the correct password you've set up for mysql.

Check the env variable in the container to get what compose really set it as password.

For reference see:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html:

> Strings containing any of the following characters must be quoted. Although you can use double quotes, for these characters it is more convenient to use single quotes, which avoids having to escape any backslash :
>
> :, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, #, ?, |, -, <, >, =, !, %, @, `

http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2772075:

> The “@” (#x40, at) and “`” (#x60, grave accent) are reserved for future use.

---

**Maybe also possible, but less likely**:

This happens because the moment when service `web` executes python command, the mysqldb in db service is not yet set up.

See mysql docker readme (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/):

> No connections until MySQL init completes
>
> If there is no database initialized when the container starts, then a
>   default database will be created. While this is the expected behavior,
>   this means that it will not accept incoming connections until such
>   initialization completes. This may cause issues when using automation
>   tools, such as docker-compose, which start several containers
>   simultaneously.

Try starting up db service (docker-compose up db) and give it several seconds and then try to run the web service.

The `depends_on` directive only waits for the container to start - docker has no knowledge when the service inside container will be 'ready' - the developer needs to implement this on his own. Usually you just set the web container to start over and over again until it finally succeeds (the db will be ready).

Also, however less recommended, is just to give a `sleep 10` before you execute your migration script.

Comment: I changed the password, remove '@' and as wel as run db first then web, now on migrate i am getting **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1130, "Host '172.24.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")** but I haven't use this IP anywhere in my project

Comment: This is the IP of the `web` container. You need to allow in db for user to connect from any host, not just 'localhost' like it's usually default in databases. In docker images, other services always connect from "outside" from database point of view.

Comment: Thanks, It's been solved by changing my.cnf file in /etc/mysql/conf.d